# How to style <strong>, <em> and then <strong><em> individually

Tags: html, css

I am using a web font from myfonts.com and I need seperate styles for:

`<em></em>` needs to be italic

`<strong></strong>` needs to be bold

`<strong><em></em></strong>` needs to be bold italic as does `<em><strong></strong></em>`

The problem with the nested tags is my CSS rules are being doubled up.

```
em strong,
strong em {
    font-family: Emblema-BoldItalic;
}

em {
    font-family: Emblema-RegularItalic;
}

strong {
    font-family: Emblema-Bold;
}
```

Comment: What's your current stylesheet?

Comment: You need to provide a complete [mcve]

Comment: Main post edited

Comment: I can't replicate your issue -- I get the desired result from your code. Are you sure the issue is in your CSS? ([JSFiddle where I tested](https://jsfiddle.net/nph/q3whw9yd/))

Comment: Hi Nathan. I think this issue may be down to font family (I edited my original post with my styles). Color seems to work fine.

Comment: You probably need to declare the single element styles first, and then overwrite them with the double element styles?

Comment: It works with font-family, too. https://jsfiddle.net/nph/q3whw9yd/2/

Comment: Are you sure you have the fonts you're wanting to use correctly configured?

Comment: @delinear that shouldn't make a difference, even if declared earlier nested styles are more precise so they should take precedence. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Which fonts are you using? Some fonts may not have a bold or italic version